# i am trying to subtract two strings and return the words in an array

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to make a program in JavaScript and below is the given code. My function needs to accept two strings *(s,t)*, where **s** is a full string and **t** is the sequence.

For instance:

- `s = "i love the moon in humming world"`
- `t = "i love moon world"`

Outputs:  `["the","in","humming"]`.

I tried a similar thing and cannot figure out why the first time my if condition don't run but then code works well. Can anyone please help? Please take care that the sequence that needed to be searched in the order they cannot search back so every time search will be continued from where the last element was found.

code:

````
function missingWords(s, t)
{
var found_index = 0;
var full_string_array = s.split(" ");
var sequence_array = t.split(" ");
var array_to_return = s.split(" ");
var searching_array = s.split(" ");
for (var i= 0 ; i < sequence_array.length ; i++)
  {
    #just trying to debug the code by two lines below
    console.log(sequence_array.length)
    console.log(found_index)

    if((array_to_return.indexOf(sequence_array[i], found_index)))
      {
        found_index = array_to_return.indexOf(sequence_array[i], found_index);
        array_to_return.splice(found_index, 1)
        found_index = found_index-1;
        console.log(array_to_return);

      }
  }
 return array_to_return;
}
console.log(missingWords("i love u in the moon of humming","i love u the of"));```

output >>
5
0
5
0
[ 'i', 'u', 'in', 'the', 'moon', 'of', 'humming' ]
5
0
[ 'i', 'in', 'the', 'moon', 'of', 'humming' ]
5
0
[ 'i', 'in', 'moon', 'of', 'humming' ]
5
1
[ 'i', 'in', 'moon', 'humming' ]
[ 'i', 'in', 'moon', 'humming' ]

**desired output**>>
without i ["in","moon","humming"]
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a mapper object and filter

1. First map the words from `t` string in mapper object as key as occurrence as value
2. split `s` and filter values based on mapper object, if it is there on mapper object and value is greater then 0 we reduce it's value by 1 and return false, else return true

```js
function missingWords(s, t) {
  let mapper = t.split(' ').reduce((op, inp) => {
    op[inp] = op[inp] || 0
    op[inp]++
    return op
  }, {})
  return s.split(' ').filter(v => {
    if (mapper[v]) {
      mapper[v]--
        return false
    }
    return true
  })
}
console.log(missingWords("i love u in the moon of humming", "i love u the of"))
```